# Excel VBA Marco to Sort Distinct Concatenation of multiple Range text values

Tags: vba, sorting, excel, concatenation, distinct

In Excel is there a optimal way to qsort concatenated values from multiple ranges where

a) concatenated values must be distinct

b) each concatenated value can have an optional before and after text (delimiter) to surround it
c) the concatenated values are sorted (qsort).

I've achieved a) and b) in the DISTINCT_CONCAT function below, but c) the qsort is not coded. **Is there an optimal way to qsort (not verbose) in the code below preferably using the [Collection Add method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265006%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) before and after parameters. Any ideas would be much appreciated** Hopefully this code will help someone else in the future with a similar problem.

#### Example Excel Formula:

For spreadsheet cells

 A1:A4 contain 21, 12, 32, 12

 B2:B4 contain 14, 08, 12

the formula macro function 

    
`=DISTINCT_CONCAT("$list.add(";"); "&CHAR(10);TRUE;Sheet1!A1:A4;Sheet2!B2:B4)`


would display in another spreadsheet cell a distinct list of range values as
    
$list.add("21");
    
$list.add("12");
    
$list.add("32");
    
$list.add("14");
    
$list.add("08");

 My preference is the function returns a sorts String of distinct range values as
    
$list.add("08");
    
$list.add("12");
    
$list.add("14");
    
$list.add("21");
    
$list.add("32");

#### DISTINCT_CONCAT function without qsort

Purpose: Distinct Concatenation of all cell values in a range, with optional before and
after text
Inputs:
beforeCellValue - optional text to appear before cell value
afterCellValue - optional text to appear after cell value
cellValueInQuotes - if true then cell value 123 appear as "123", otherwise 123
cellValueRange - one or more ranges to be concatenated, using the text value of the range
Returns: concatenated string

`Public Function DISTINCT_CONCAT( ByVal beforeCellValue As String, ByVal afterCellValue As String, ByVal cellValueInQuotes As Boolean, ParamArray cellValueRange() As Variant) As String`

```
  Dim c As Collection, i As Long, cell As Range
  Set c = New Collection
  For i = LBound(cellValueRange) To UBound(cellValueRange)
    For Each cell In cellValueRange(i)
        If Len(cell.text) > 0 Then
            On Error Resume Next
            c.Add cell.value, cell.text ' distinct collection (no duplicates)
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
    Next cell
    Set cell = Nothing
  Next i

  Dim returnText As String
  Dim value As Variant
  For Each value In c
    If cellValueInQuotes Then
        returnText = returnText & beforeCellValue & Chr(34) & value & Chr(34) & afterCellValue
    Else
        returnText = returnText & beforeCellValue & value & afterCellValue
    End If
  Next value
  DISTINCT_CONCAT = returnText
End Function
```

Comment: Just curious, what is this used for?

Comment: Isn't your `cellValueInQuotes` redundant? If the user wants quotes they could append/prepend them to the `beforeCellValue` and `afterCellValue` parameters

Comment: Yes the would append quotes, but this means adding CHAR(34) 2 times to the formula string which makes it unreadable. For instance: <br> =DISTINCT_CONCAT("$list.add("&CHAR(34);CHAR(34)&"); "&CHAR(10);TRUE,Sheet1!A1:A4,Sheet2!B2:B4)

Comment: joseph4tw, it to add dynamic action code to a drools rules decision table (.xls). This decision table is then transformed to a drools rules language file (.drl) which is loaded by the drools rule engine at runtime, used within an Expert system.

Comment: Or you can use double-doublequotes in the string: **=DISTINCT_CONCAT("$list.add(""";"""); "&CHAR(10);TRUE,Sheet1!A1:A4,Sheet2!B2:B4)**

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to use a quicksort?

Comment: Thanks Zev Spitz, I will try the double quotes.

Comment: QSort is an inappropriate name. Its purpose is to order the values (product ids) that appear in the cell, so it make it easier for business to examine the product ids in the decision table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Scripting.Dictionary` enforces uniqueness on the keys without any error handling, but it cannot be sorted.

A .NET `System.Collections.ArrayList` has a `Sort` method that uses quicksort.

This assumes a reference to the `Microsoft Scripting Runtime`.

```
Public Function DISTINCT_CONCAT(ByVal beforeCellValue As String, ByVal afterCellValue As String, ByVal cellValueInQuotes As Boolean, ParamArray cellValueRange() As Variant) As String
Dim i As Long, cell As Variant, dict As New Dictionary, items As Variant, al As Variant, item As Variant
Dim delimiter As String, returnText As String

For i = 0 To UBound(cellValueRange)
    For Each cell In cellValueRange(i)
        dict(cell.Text) = cell.value
    Next
Next

Set al = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
items = dict.items
For Each item In items
    al.Add item
Next
al.Sort

'Doing this here limits the number of string concatenations, as does using
'the Join function
If cellValueInQuotes Then
    beforeCellValue = beforeCellValue & Chr(34)
    afterCellValue = Chr(34) & afterCellValue
End If

DISTINCT_CONCAT = beforeCellValue & Join(al.ToArray, afterCellValue & beforeCellValue) & afterCellValue
End Function
```

Don't reinvent the wheel, unless you need a better one. :)

Comment: Nice solution Zev. Its easy to see I'm not a .NET programmer. My background is J2EE.

Comment: This solution ***may*** be a dead-end if you end up wishing to change the sorting criterion in pure VBA.

Comment: @keepAlive An alternative might be to use [SortedList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.sortedlist) -- it's non-generic so it can be used from VBA, and items are returned sorted by the key AFAICT. Each element would be added with the key to sort by. I'll update the answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 0):

This was an odd one. I tried using traditional sorting methods on the Collection object, but code would stop execution, without error, when it deleted a key and try to add another one. Weird. Since you're trying to keep only unique values, I kept the Collection object there. However, I put the contents into an array, sorted the array, then used the array to display the values.

```
Option Explicit

Public Function DISTINCT_CONCAT(ByVal beforeCellValue As String, ByVal afterCellValue As String, ByVal cellValueInQuotes As Boolean, ParamArray cellValueRange() As Variant) As String

    Dim c As Collection, i As Long, cell As Range
    Set c = New Collection
    For i = LBound(cellValueRange) To UBound(cellValueRange)
    For Each cell In cellValueRange(i)
        If Len(cell.Text) > 0 Then
            On Error Resume Next
            c.Add cell.value, cell.Text ' distinct collection (no duplicates)
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
    Next cell
    Set cell = Nothing
    Next i



    Dim arr() As Long
    ReDim arr(1 To c.Count)
    For i = 1 To c.Count
        arr(i) = c(i)
    Next i

    ' sort array
    Dim j As Long, k As Long
    Dim temp As Long
    For j = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        For k = j + 1 To UBound(arr)
            If (arr(j) > arr(k)) Then
                temp = arr(k)
                arr(k) = arr(j)
                arr(j) = temp
            End If
        Next k
    Next j


    Dim returnText As String
    Dim value As Variant

    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If cellValueInQuotes Then
            returnText = returnText & beforeCellValue & Chr(34) & arr(i) & Chr(34) & afterCellValue
        Else
            returnText = returnText & beforeCellValue & arr(i) & afterCellValue
        End If
    Next i
    DISTINCT_CONCAT = returnText
End Function
```

Comment: Hi joseph4tw, thanks for your input. Soon after posting the question, I got the traditional sorting methods on the Collection object working using QSort and Swap functions in the answer above. But stackoverflow imposed a 6 hour wait before i could post my solution. It's been 12 years since I looked at VBA, so it take a short while to get back into the swing of things.

Comment: 12 years, eh? Well you definitely look like you still got it :) I look forward to seeing your solution

Answer (score 0):

OK, in the meantime I came up with a quick sort function for the Collection of distinct range values. The function DISTINCT_CONCAT now takes an additional sort type parameter [0 (no sort), 1 (sort ascending), 2 (sort descending)].

This maybe helpful to somebody. Here is the code. If anyone thinks there is a more optimal solution, please feel free to update the code.

 
Where spreadsheet cells 

Sheet1 - A1:A4 contain 21, 12, 32, 12 

Sheet2 - B2:B4 contain 14, 08, 12

 
the Formula 
    `=DISTINCT_CONCAT("$list.add(""";"""); "&CHAR(10);1;Sheet1!A1:A4;Sheet2!B2:B4`    

will now return a concatenated sorted asc String of distinct range values with desired text either side of each value as 

$list.add("08");

$list.add("12"); 

$list.add("14"); 

$list.add("21"); 

$list.add("32");

I wrote DISTINCT_CONCAT a more optimal solution then using the limited native Excel function CONCATENATE.

```
Purpose: Distinct Concatenation of all cell values in a range, with optional before and after text
Inputs:  
   beforeValue - optional text to appear before cell value
   afterValue - optional text to appear after cell value
   sortType - sort distinct cell values, use 0 (no sort), 1 (sort ascending), 2 (sort descending)
   rangeOfValues- one or more ranges to be concatenated, using the text value of the range
Returns: a range of values as a distinct concatenated string optionally sorted with before and after text

Public Function DISTINCT_CONCAT( _
      ByVal beforeValue As String, _
      ByVal afterValue As String, _
      ByVal sortType As Integer, _
      ParamArray rangeOfValues() As Variant) As String

    ' add range of values to distinct collection
    Dim c As Collection, i As Long, cell As Range
    Set c = New Collection
    For i = LBound(rangeOfValues) To UBound(rangeOfValues)
        For Each cell In rangeOfValues(i)
            If Len(cell.text) > 0 Then
                On Error Resume Next
                c.Add cell.value, cell.text ' ignores duplicates
                On Error GoTo 0
            End If
        Next cell
        Set cell = Nothing
    Next i

    ' optional sort
    Call Sort(c, sortType)

    ' concatenation distinct values into a string with optional before and after value delimitors
    Dim text As String
    Dim value As Variant
    For Each value In c
        text = text & beforeValue & value & afterValue
    Next value
    DISTINCT_CONCAT = text
End Function
```

```
Private Function Sort(ByRef c As Collection, ByVal sortType As Integer)
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    If sortType < 1 And sortType > 2 Then Exit Function

    For i = 1 To c.Count - 1
        For j = i + 1 To c.Count
            If sortType = 1 Then
                If c(i) > c(j) Then Swap c, i, j
            ElseIf sortType = 2 Then
                If c(i) < c(j) Then Swap c, i, j
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Function
```

```
Private Function Swap(ByRef c As Collection, ByVal i As Long, ByVal j As Long)
    c.Add c(j), , , i
    c.Add c(i), , , j + 1
    c.Remove i
    c.Remove j
End Function
```